# How can I determine if my EF 6 database initializer will run or not?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I would like to know if my set database initializer will run or not. I set my database initializer as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
        Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }
```

An here is what I would like to know:

```
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", false)
    {
        // Here I would like to know if the initializer will run or not.
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain what do you want to do exactly that depends on execution of initializer?

Comment: Its long... but anyway: I want to attach event handlers to my ObjectContext. However DbContext's ObjectContext property (which I must access) is lazy initialized, so when I access it, then it triggers to run the DbInitializer. This cause the DbInitializer run earlier than the DbContext (and Owin) initialized properly an cause error. So I figured out, this case I can not access ObjectContext in the DbContext constructor, instead attach the event hanlders in my DbIntializer.first statement. The only problem then: If the DbIntitalizer will not run, I still should attach the handlers.

Comment: The initializer will not run before you actually *do* something with the context. When the constructor has run, the context itself doesn't even know yet whether it will run the initializer. I think you should add guards in the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are three by default database initialization strategies, they are:

**CreateDatabaseIfNotExists:** The default initializer. It will create the database if none exists as per the configuration. Take in mind that if you change the model class and then run the application with this initializer, then it will throw an exception.

**DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges:** This initializer drops an existing database and creates a new database, if your model classes have been changed. So you don't have to worry about maintaining your database schema, when your model classes change.

**DropCreateDatabaseAlways:** As the name suggests, this initializer drops an existing database every time you run the application, irrespective of whether your model classes have changed or not.

All of them inheritates from **IDatabaseInitializer**.

Now, you can extend your database initializer to do something more, like in your case, get notified.

To do such you need to set it in *web.config* and create a custom initializer which will then override the seed method which will be called in every instance. This method can notify your application of such situation.

Take in mind that here i am overriding the *DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges* cause I intend to keep it behavior, you can extend *IDatabaseInitializer* and override his *InitializeDatabase* method if you want your own behavior.

Here you have a sample code:

```
class ContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Dbc>
{
    protected override void Seed(Dbc context)
    {
        // Here you can notify you before any change got executed
        InitializeDatabase(context);
    }
}
```

And here it is the web.config content:

```
<!--Context.Dbc is the namespace qualified class of my context. Context is the DLL that it is found in.-->
<!--Context.ContextInitalizer is the namespace qualified class of my custom initializer. Context is the DLL that it is found in.-->
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <!-- This specifies that EF has an initializer -->
    <contexts>
      <context type="Context.Dbc, Context">
        <databaseInitializer type="Context.ContextInitializer, Context"></databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <!--End initializer-->
</entityFramework>
```

Sample code: http://brandonclapp.com/entity-framework-custom-database-initializer-from-web-config/